# Subtract a Number from variable which contains a sentence

Tags: shell, awk, string

This is extended question from

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081168/reading-a-log-file-with-different-sequences-using-shell-script

I'm new to shell. I've written a shell script a code with finds a sentence I want to subtract the value from that sentence. the sentence is as below

```
FINAL SINGLE POINT ENERGY       -39.022584378179
```

I want the numerical part, expr substr gives me unknown command error and actually the lenght of my numerical part may vary so I wanted to use awk something like:

```
awk -F" " '{ print $1 }' $line
```

can you guys help me

here's my code

```
optimized=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    *"HURRAY"*)
      optimized=1
      continue
      ;;
    "FINAL SINGLE POINT ENERGY      "*)
      [ "$optimized" = 1 ] || continue
      final_energy=`echo $line | awk '{print $NF }'`
      echo "Found optimized final energy: $final_energy"
      ;;
    "final energy")
  esac
done < input-s.out
```

the log file is a long file contains many `FINAL SINGLE POINT ENERGY`" and has to read only the last one which comes after `hurray`.

Comment: you should understand the use of final_energy=${line#*:} . In this colon (:) is used but in your input data line no colon is present.

Comment: try this final_energy=`echo $line | awk '{ print $NF }'`

Comment: ah, you're right it's a bug, I forgot to remove it

Comment: @ShravanYadav it gives me "awk: can't open file FINAL"

Comment: please add the ouput after running the script and also the error in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/HURRAY/ { ok = 1 } ok == 1 && /^FINAL SINGLE POINT ENERGY/ { printf("Found optimized final energy: %s\n", $NF) }' input-s.out
```

I think this does what your shell script is trying to do.

If it finds the string `HURRAY` somewhere, it sets `ok` to 1 (your `optimized` variable).  If `ok` is 1 and it finds a line starting with the string `FINAL SINGLE POINT ENERGY`, it displays the message followed by the value in the last column of that same line.